# Problems deploying Sinatra app to staging environment

Tags: ruby, sinatra, capistrano

I have a small Sinatra app with both a staging and production environment on a single server with running Nginx.  To deploy I am using Capistrano and capistrano-ext to easily deploy to different locations.

The problem that the staging environment always runs with the production configuration specified within the app.rb file.

```
configure :staging do
  # staging settings
  set :foo, "bar"   # will never be set to this
end

configure :production do
  # prod settings
  set :foo, "rab"
end
```

I have come to the conclusion that the capistrano :environment variable within the deploy.rb file doesn't config Sinatra in any way.  I have also tried setting the ENV["RACK_ENV"] to "staging" to no avail.

config/deploy/staging.rb

```
server "10.10.100.16", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/staging.my_app" 
set :environment, "staging"
set :env, "staging"          
ENV["RACK_ENV"] = "staging"
```

Any ideas?

** Update: I should add that I am also using Passenger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setting the rack_env variable within the nginx seems to do the trick.

http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#RackEnv